# Can someone abuse LINQ and solve this money puzzle?

Tags: c#, linq, math

For the fun of it, I would like to see someone use and abuse LINQ to solve this money problem.
I really have no idea how you would do it - I suppose Populating some set and then selecting off of it.

If given a total number of coins and give the total amount of all coins added together:
Show every possible combination of coins. Coins are Quarters(.25), Dimes(.10) Nickels(.05) and Pennies(.01)

Include the option so that there can be zero of a type of coin or there must be at least 1 of each.

Sample Problem: If I have 19 coins and the coins add up to $1.56 and there must be at least 1 of every type of coin.

The answer would be:

> 1 Quarters, 9 Dimes, 8 Nickels, 1 Pennies
>
> 2 Quarters, 5 Dimes, 11 Nickels, 1 Pennies
>
> 2 Quarters, 9 Dimes, 2 Nickels, 6 Pennies
>
> 3 Quarters, 1 Dimes, 14 Nickels, 1 Pennies
>
> 3 Quarters, 5 Dimes, 5 Nickels, 6 Pennies
>
> 4 Quarters, 1 Dimes, 8 Nickels, 6 Pennies
>
> 5 Quarters, 1 Dimes, 2 Nickels, 11 Pennies

And if we allowed zero for a coint we allowed get an additional
0 Quarters, 13 Dimes, 5 Nickels, 1 Pennies

Here is some sample C# code using a brute force method to solve the problem.
Don't bother improving the sample, let's just see a solution using Linq.
//Try not to use any regualar c# looping code if possible.

```
private void SolveCoinProblem(int totalNumberOfCoins, double totalAmount, int minimumNumberOfEachCoin)
    {
        int foundCount = 0;
        long numberOfTries = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Solving Coin Problem:TotalNumberOfCoins={0}TotalAmount={1}MinimumNumberOfEachCoin{2}", totalNumberOfCoins, totalAmount, minimumNumberOfEachCoin));
        for (int totalQuarters = minimumNumberOfEachCoin; totalQuarters < totalNumberOfCoins; totalQuarters++)
        {
            for (int totalDimes = minimumNumberOfEachCoin; totalDimes < totalNumberOfCoins; totalDimes++)
            {
                for (int totalNickels = minimumNumberOfEachCoin; totalNickels < totalNumberOfCoins; totalNickels++)
                {
                    for (int totalPennies = minimumNumberOfEachCoin; totalPennies < totalNumberOfCoins; totalPennies++)
                    {
                        numberOfTries++;
                        if (totalQuarters + totalDimes + totalNickels + totalPennies == totalNumberOfCoins)
                        {
                            if (Math.Round((totalQuarters * .25) + (totalDimes * .10) + (totalNickels * .05) + (totalPennies * .01),2) == totalAmount)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Quarters, {1} Dimes, {2} Nickels, {3} Pennies", totalQuarters, totalDimes, totalNickels, totalPennies));
                                foundCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Combinations Found. We tried {1} combinations.", foundCount, numberOfTries));
    }
```

Comment: Using LINQ to solve this would hardly be abuse! :-)

Comment: btw, the reason your code finds 5 (not 7) answers is because of rounding errors. Switch to decimal throughout (0.05M, etc) and you might be surprised!

Comment: Re "floating point BS" - that isn't BS; that is simply how floating point works. The rule of thumb: if you see "float" (or "double") and "money" in the same sentence, it is probably wrong.

Answer (score 21):

Untested, but:

```
        int minQuarters = 1, minDimes = 1,
            minNickels = 1, minPennies = 1,
            maxQuarters = 19, maxDimes = 19,
            maxNickels = 19, maxPennies = 19,
            coinCount = 19, total = 156;
        var qry = from q in Enumerable.Range(minQuarters, maxQuarters)
                  from d in Enumerable.Range(minDimes, maxDimes)
                  from n in Enumerable.Range(minNickels, maxNickels)
                  from p in Enumerable.Range(minPennies, maxPennies)
                  where q + d + n + p == coinCount
                  where q * 25 + d * 10 + n * 5 + p == total
                  select new {q,d,n,p};
        foreach (var row in qry)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} quarter(s), {1} dime(s), {2} nickel(s) and {3} pennies",
                row.q, row.d, row.n, row.p);
        }
```

---

Actually, for retail purposes - perhaps a better query is "what is the fewest coins I can give out"? Replace with:

```
...
from p in Enumerable.Range(minPennies, maxPennies)
where q + d + n + p <= coinCount
where q * 25 + d * 10 + n * 5 + p == total
orderby q + d + n + p
...
```

and use either `First()` or `Take(...)` ;-p

You could also probably reduce the number of checked cases by subtracting (for example) `q` in the `maxDimes` test (and so on...) - something like (simplified):

```
        int minCount = 1,
            coinCount = 19, total = 156;
        var qry = from q in Enumerable.Range(minCount, coinCount - (3 * minCount))
                  where q * 25 <= total
                  from d in Enumerable.Range(minCount, coinCount - (q + (2 * minCount)))
                  where q * 25 + d * 10 <= total
                  from n in Enumerable.Range(minCount, coinCount - (q + d + minCount))
                  where q * 25 + d * 10 + n * 5 <= total
                  from p in Enumerable.Range(minCount, coinCount - (q + d + n))
                  where q + d + n + p == coinCount
                  where q * 25 + d * 10 + n * 5 + p == total
                  select new { q, d, n, p };
```

Comment: That was a darn fast answer.
You do have all the answers in your returned set but it appears it is also returning results that are incorrect. LINQ Query Found 35 results , Of which only 5 (same as mine) meet the criteria of 19 counts with a total of $1.56.

Comment: +1 Brute Force, if it doesn't work you're not using enough of it.

Comment: 35? I get 7 from the query I posted, and they all look fine.

Comment: The other two being "1 quarter(s), 9 dime(s), 8 nickel(s) and 1 pennies", and "5 quarter(s), 1 dime(s), 2 nickel(s) and 11 pennies"

Comment: Your code is working great. It is finding 7. In fact, it pointed out a problem in the brute force method. Two of the items in the brute force method are being left out because the line where its checking the total is doing some floating point BS and is evaluating to 1.59999 instead of 1.59.